# Equation Plotting

Tags: plotting, modeling

I'm using the mean field theory approximation and the Ising Model for magnetization to come up with the following equation:

`m(T) = tanh(m(T)/T)`

where T is an arbitrary temperature

I'm now trying to plot the left side of the equation (m(T)) and the right side of the equation `(tanh(m(T)/T)` over a range of `x -> [-2,2], y-> [-1.1, 1.1], T -> [0.2,2]` in steps of 0,2

Separately I also want to graph the solution `m(T) = tanh(m(T)/T)` for `T -> [0,2]` as a continuous function

What syntax would I use?

Comment: Have a look at `FindRoot`.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Mathematica?  Look up `ContourPlot`.  Also, I don't understand how the range of `x` and `y` enters into plotting an equation that contains no `x` or `y`.

Comment: What the relations between `x`, `y`, and `T`

Answer (score 1):

Try ( see @MichaelE2 's comment )

```
 ContourPlot[m == Tanh[m /T], {T, .2, 2}, {m, -1, 1},FrameLabel -> {T, m}, MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]